# MySQL: remove number prefix from all records

Tags: php, mysql, sql, php-5.3

I have this `page` table below and I want to remove the numbering prefix of '**999**' from the column of `template_id`,

```
page_id    template_id    url
1          9991           a
2          9992           b
3          9993           c
4          4              d
```

so I can get the updated data below,

```
page_id    template_id    url
1          1              a
2          2              b
3          3              c
4          4              d
```

Any idea how I can remove this kind of prefix?

Comment: It is type of `integer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to make a complex query or if you need futher operation you can do:

```
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
   $newTemplateID = (string) $r['template_id'];
   if (substr($newTemplateID,0,3) === 999 ) {
     $newTemplateID = substr($newTemplateID,3);

     mysql_query("UPDATE tbl 
                    SET template_id = {$newTemplateID} 
                    WHERE page_id = {$r['page_id']} 
                    LIMIT 1");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

To obtain the data as shown in your question:

```
SELECT
  page_id,
  SUBSTRING(template_id, IF(template_id RLIKE '^999', 4, 1)) AS template_id,
  url
FROM page
```

Or, if you want to permanently update the table:

```
UPDATE page
SET template_id = SUBSTRING(template_id, 4)
WHERE template_id RLIKE '^999'
```

MySQL's [implicit type conversion](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/type-conversion.html) will handle the rest.

Comment: Can you use string operations on integer columns in mysql? I wasn't sure.

Comment: @dqhendricks: See the link in my answer: they'll automatically get cast to strings (in the connection's character set as of 5.5.3, or as `binary` before that; either way, I believe `SUBSTRING` and `RLIKE '^999'` should work fine).